# How to make polygon from > 100 000 points?

Tags: java, awt, polygon

I'm trying to make Polygons from my file (x, y, z).
I have a lot of lines so I don't know how many records should be in every Polygon.
I think that I should do it when I'm loading file:

```
 while (file.hasNextDouble()) {
            a = br.nextDouble();
            b = br.nextInt();
            c = br.nextInt();
            vertices.add(new Vertice(a, b, c));
 }
```

Please, tell me how should I fix that loading code. Could you tell me how can I add e.g. every third record (a, b, c) to a new Polygon?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Is this code not working? Or do you want to improve it?

Comment: @Laerte, This cod is working but this is making only new object Vertice and added him to my list - vertices.
I want to fix it to make also new Polygon object in the same code. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you know how many vertices each polygon has? Is there any way to identify them in the file?

Comment: I don't know.. I have a lot of vertices and I don't know how many (x,y,z) should I add to one Polygon. I try to connect vertices.

Comment: If you need to make polygon from several vertices and you want them to be certain, you should have a way to identify them in the file. If you don't have a way to identify them, you could make polygons with `n` vertices, where `n` is a random number.

Comment: @Laerte okay thanks but can you give me example in code how can I make new Polygon from every third lines? It should be for loop?

Comment: I've posted as an answer. Check if it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a polygon every 3 vertices. I didn't test it, but that's the idea:

```
    int i = 0;
int polySize = 3;
List<Polygon> polyList = new List<Polygon>();
Polygon poly = new Polygon();

while (file.hasNextDouble()) {
    a = br.nextDouble();
    b = br.nextInt();
    c = br.nextInt();
    vertice = new Vertice(a, b, c);
    poly.add(vertice);

    if (i == polySize-1)
    {
        polyList.add(poly);
        poly = new Polygon();
        i = 0;
    }
    i++;
}
```